# Not allow special characters in expiration date except /

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive that should not allow any special character except '/'. This is written for expiration date and hence should not allow anything other than numbers. I have been successful but it is still allowing special characters. Below is my code:

```
appModule.directive('numbersSlash', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input.
                // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
                // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
                if (inputValue === undefined) {
                    return '';
                }
                // A regular expression validates the use of numbers
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^/\0-9]/g, '');
                // If slash at first
                if(transformedInput =="/"){
                  transformedInput = '';
                }
                if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Kindly inform what changes can be done for my regex pattern. Currently it is allowing special characters and multiple /.

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple `/` or do you want something more precise? You should really use `.replace(/[^\/0-9]/g, '');` or there is another issue with unescaped delimiter.

Comment: This looks ok - http://regexr.com/3ciqb what special characters is it allowing? Is it any numbers and one slash? 78/77 or 787/ or /1231 ?

Comment: I want that if more than one / is provided by the user it should not be allowed just like we do not allow more than one / in expiration date. Currently it is also accepting special characters like #,$,% etc.

Comment: Currently it allows inputs like #1/$4.

Answer (score 0):

To match 01/20 try the regular expression `/\d\d\/\d\d/g` <sup>1</sup>
E.g. http://regexr.com/3ciqh

Instead of stripping, try matching:

```
var isValid = /^(\d\d\/\d\d)$/.test('01/20');
// true

var isValid = /^(\d\d\/\d\d)$/.test('$1/20');
// false
```

<sup>1</sup> There are probably far more graceful ways of doing this.

Comment: I have a specific requirement not to allow any special characters. Else the above can be used.  This will allow special characters to be later will inform the user that it is not a valid input. Which is not my requirement currently. Thanks anyways.